# Scala inheritance from Java class with generic types in constructor

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop, existential-type

How can I extends a Java class that expects a `Map<?, ?>` in its constructor in Scala?

The Java class looks like

```java
public class MyJavaClass {

  private final Map<String, ?> originals;

  public MyJavaClass(Map<?, ?> originals,  Map<String, ?> configProviderProps, boolean doLog) { ... }

  public MyJavaClass(Map<?, ?> originals) {
    this(originals, Collections.emptyMap(), true);
  }
}
```

In Scala I was trying to do something like below but my IDE tells my that it "cannot resolve overloaded Constructor":

```scala
class myScalaClass[K <: AnyRef, V <: AnyRef](origi: Map[K, V]) extends MyJavaClass(origi) { ... }
```

Also tried to replace `AnyRef` with `java.lang.Object` without success. I am using Java 8 and Scala 2.12.11.

Comment: Would wildcards work for you or do you have to know the types K and V? Also, I don't think you need an upper bound at all

Comment: Actually, scratch that, you don't need wildcards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
class myScalaClass(origi: java.util.Map[_, _]) extends MyJavaClass(origi) {  }
```